# remove html tags from string js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show a text that i'm getting from the server with html tags.

Let's say i got

```
"a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\n"
```

and i want to show

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

i tried using jquery text() but i get empty string:

```
var answer = params.question.answer;
$('#answer_text').html($(answer).text());
```

i also tried with regex but nothing happens:

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
var answer = params.question.answer.replace(regex, '');
$('#answer_text').html(answer);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `\n` into `<br/>` for creating line breaks in html:

```
var answer= "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\n";
$('#answer_text').html(answer.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/566f7nov/)**

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: something is really wierd. if i'll do exactly the same it will work but if i'll change  var answer= "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\n"; to var answer = params.question.answer it won't work. the value from params.question.answer is exactly as   "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\n"

Comment: what does ` params.question.answer` alerts??

Comment: it's a value i get from json and passing it to the function. the value inside is a string with "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\n"

Comment: what about `$('#answer_text').html(params.question.answer.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));`

Comment: i'm getting - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: that means `params.question.answer` is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Using REGEX Remove `\n` and add `<br />` tag.

Try:

```
var answer = "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\n";
var regex = /\n/gi;
$('#answer_text').html(answer.replace(regex, "<br />"));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ao09cvm/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) rule

```js
var answer = "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\n";
$('#answer_text').html(answer);
```

```css
#answer_text {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="answer_text"></div>
```